# android layout landscape/portrait with different options

Tags: android, layout, landscape-portrait

Is there any way to *directly* tell android which layout resource to choose for landscape or portrait mode?

I know normally it's simple, put the normal "main_layout.xml" in the "res/layout" folder and the landscape "main_layout.xml" in the "res/layout-land" folder.

Now assume I have two layouts called "main_layout_blue.xml" and "main_layout_red.xml". The user can choose one of them and I can set the appropriate layout. On orientation change again all is fine.

Where I get stuck is by giving the user an option to set different layouts for different orienations like "main_layout_blue.xml" for portrait mode and "main_layout_red.xml" for landscape mode.

Is there an android option to explicitly tell the system to use "res/layout/main_layout_blue.xml" for the portrait orientation and "res/layout-land/main_layout_red.xml" for the landscape orientation?
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

After the orientation change, the view will be recreated so you can check the orientation of the device by the following:

```
Activity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
```

and based on the result you can:

```
   if(portrait)
      setContentView(R.layout.blue)
   else
      setContentView(R.layout.red)
```

but keep in mind to put all of the resources in /layout folder

Comment: Hello Pooya. I forgot to mention that atm this is my favored workaround. I just hoped there might be a way to avoid explicitly listening for orientation changes by declaring which resource to choose when beforehand.

Comment: @Marchand since you are letting user choose at runtime the preferred layout, you need to put some logic in your code to find the user preferences and link it to your available layouts